# How to append a delimiter between multiple values coming from a repeating field in xquery

Tags: xpath, xquery

I have a xml file which has a repeating element generating multiple values.
I would like to split all the values generated from that xpath delimited by any delimiter like , `|_`
I have tried the following which did not work -

```
tokenize(/*:ShippedUnit/*:Containment/*:ContainerManifest/*:Consignments/*:Consignment/*:ConsignmentHeader/*:ConsignmentRef, '\s')

replace(/*:ShippedUnit/*:Containment/*:ContainerManifest/*:Consignments/*:Consignment/*:ConsignmentHeader/*:ConsignmentRef," ","_")
```

**example :**

Now getting - **CBR123 CBR678 CBR656**

Expecting to get - **CBR123|CBR678|CBR656**

**Note :** In some transactions, there can be only one value present for that xpath. And therefore replace doesnot work here

Comment: Without a sample (even simplified) of your source XML, it's difficult to provide an answer. Could you please post one?

Comment: <ShippedUnit>
<Containment>
<ContainerManifest>
<Consignments>
<Consignment>
<ConsignmentHeader>
<ConsignmentRef>CBR00464833N</ConsignmentRef>
<ConsignmentNotes />
</ConsignmentHeader>
</Consignment>
</Consignments>
<Consignments>
<Consignment>
<ConsignmentHeader>
<ConsignmentRef>CBR01264878K</ConsignmentRef>
<ConsignmentNotes />
</ConsignmentHeader>
</Consignment>
</Consignments>
</ContainerManifest>
</Containment>
</ShippedUnit>

Comment: Please see above the fragment of the XML.

Comment: Thanks! Could you confirm that the expected result from this input is `CBR00464833N|CBR01264878K`?

Comment: Yes it works as expected . Thanks Joe .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the expected result assuming the sample source XML added to the comments in the original post, use the `fn:string-join()` function:

```
string-join(
    //ConsignmentRef,
    "|"
)
```

This will return:

```
CBR00464833N|CBR01264878K
```

For more on this function, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-string-join.

Answer (score 1):

Another option in XQuery 3.1 would be

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method 'text';
declare option output:item-separator '|';

//ConsignmentRef
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. I am using string-join for now but this too works as expected.